# acosl is not in the std namespace?

Tags: c++, c++11

According to cppreference, the function `acosl` should be in the std namespace : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/acos

However, with gcc (or clang), the code below does not compile :

```
#include <cmath>                                                                 

int main()                                                                       
{                                                                                
        long double var = std::acosl(4.0);                                      
        return 0;                                                                
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
gay@latitude-7490:~$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:5:26: error: 'acosl' is not a member of 'std'; did you mean 'acosh'?
    5 |  long double truc = std::acosl( (long double)4.0);
      |                          ^~~~~
      |                          acosh
```

What am I missing ? Am I misreading cppreference ?

Comment: Which version of GCC? Hmm seems reproducible in [GCC 4.9.2](http://cpp.sh/22xpm)

Comment: @CoryKramer 9.2 and trunc fails. `acosl` without `std::` succeeds.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on, but both `acosl(4.0)` and `std::acos(4.0l)` do work. Also, adding `-stdlib=libc++` makes `std::acosl(4.0)` work in Clang.

Comment: @CoryKramer I tried it with gcc-7, gcc-8 and gcc-9

Comment: I think this is a GCC issue, or at least a libstdc++ issue.  Code works fine with clang [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qz7XATCewcDBlSpu) which uses libc++

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79700

Comment: @cpplearner Good find!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a libstdc++ bug.

`cmath` in libstdc++ doesn't just wrap an `#include <math.h>` in `namespace std`: it defines new functions that delegate to built-ins. I guess a definition wants adding to [this source code](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/c_std/cmath). It was probably just an oversight when C++11 (via C99) introduced the function. (Though notice that the `acos(long double __x)` overload delegates to `__builtin_acosl`!)

In Clang, switching to libc++ resolves the issue. With libstdc++, using the global namespace version of `acosl` should also work.

<strike>You should [raise a bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=gcc).</strike> I think it's covered by [bug #79700](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79700).